# Comparing and combining dictonaries

Tags: python

I have a list with a varying amount of dictionaries contained within it.

I need to loop over each dictionary in input and compared the key values 's_source_zone' 's_destination_zone' and 'Services'. If these key values match, i need to combine them (Keys Source IP and Destination IP) into one dictionary stored within result []. If they do not match, the input dictionary needs to be added to result.

Essentially consolidating all "matching" dictionaries into one. See below example

```
    result = []
    input_ = [{'s_logical_system': 'logical_1', 's_virtual_router': 'vr_1', 's_matched_route': '10.0.0.0/8', 's_source_zone': 'zone_cccc_1', 's_destination_zone': 'zone_bbbb_1', 'Services': 80, 'Source IP': '10.10.10.10', 'Destination IP': '10.20.20.20'}, {'s_logical_system': 'logical_1', 's_virtual_router': 'vr_1', 's_matched_route': '10.0.0.0/8', 's_source_zone': 'zone_cccc_1', 's_destination_zone': 'zone_bbbb_1', 'Services': 80, 'Source IP': '10.40.10.10', 'Destination IP': '10.10.50.20'}, {'s_logical_system': 'logical_3', 's_virtual_router': 'vr_2', 's_matched_route': '10.0.0.0/8', 's_source_zone': 'zone_zzzz_1', 's_destination_zone': 'zone_rrrr_1', 'Services': 443, 'Source IP': '10.10.10.10', 'Destination IP': '10.20.20.20'}]

    if 's_source_zone', 's_destination_zone' and 'Services' all have the same values, combine the keys "Source IP" and "Destination IP" into one dictionary appended to result[]. See below;

    result = [{'s_logical_system': 'logical_1', 's_virtual_router': 'vr_1', 's_matched_route': '10.0.0.0/8', 's_source_zone': 'zone_cccc_1', 's_destination_zone': 'zone_bbbb_1', 'Services': 80, 'Source IP': '10.10.10.10, 10.40.10.10', 'Destination IP': '10.20.20.20, 10.10.50.20'}, {'s_logical_system': 'logical_3', 's_virtual_router': 'vr_2', 's_matched_route': '10.0.0.0/8', 's_source_zone': 'zone_zzzz_1', 's_destination_zone': 'zone_rrrr_1', 'Services': 443, 'Source IP': '10.10.10.10', 'Destination IP': '10.20.20.20'}]

if match not found. Append the entire dictionary to result. result.append(input_[x])
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @PaulRooney Hi Paul, I cannot show the exact subset of information, but let me give you an example.

`code` input = {'s_source_zone': 'zone1', 'source ip': '10.0.0.1', 'destination ip': '10.1.1.1', 's_destination_zone': 'zone3'}`code`

This is variable, there could be 20 dictonaries with different data within them, they all sit within a list [{}].

The expected result is to iterate over all of the dicts within the list, create a new list/dict combo and combine the dicts with the same s_source_zone, s_destination_zone into one dict.

Hope this is clear

Comment: Yes I'm not asking you to reveal any specific information, just to show a representative example. You already have example input (?) in `dict1, dict2, dict3`, so what would be the output given those inputs?

Comment: @PaulRooney Combine all dictionaries that have the same value of "x" key.

Basically if dict[key] == data[key] combine these 2 dictionaries. However it needs to iterate over a random amount of dictionaries, could be 10 could be 70.

Comment: By combine you mean add all the values of duplicates to a list?

Comment: Hi @PaulRooney I have updated my question with an easier to read explanation,  please see first set of code input

Comment: @BradSolomon Hi Brad, I have updated the question again to try be more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

match_on = ['s_source_zone', 's_destination_zone', 'Services',
            's_logical_system', 's_virtual_router']
groupfunc = lambda x: [x[match] for match in match_on]

result = []
for (source, dest, service, log, virt), group in groupby(input_, groupfunc):
    group_ = tuple(group)  # otherwise iterator goes bye-bye
    res = {'Destination IP': ', '.join(d['Destination IP'] for d in group_),
           'Services': service,
           'Source IP': ', '.join(d['Source IP'] for d in group_),
           's_destination_zone': dest,
           's_logical_system': log,
           's_matched_route': ', '.join(d['s_matched_route'] for d in group_),
           's_source_zone': source,
           's_virtual_router': virt}
    result.append(res)
```

Inferring a bit from your example, it looks like there are actually 5 key/value pairs on which you want to match.  (Otherwise, you would've combined the duplicate/same values in some way, which you did not.)

The lambda func here matches the dictionaries within your input based on them having the intersection of equivalent values for the 5 keys in `match_on`.  All of the matching dictionaries are thrown into a `group`, which here is an `itertools._grouper` iterator.